# Automating detection of when shared_ptr should really be unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I'm working with a large c++ code base that has evolved and organically grown over the last 10 years. One of the items I've been looking at is when shared_ptr's (via make_shared) are "overused", where they could easily be unique_ptr's instead.

We've made diligent progress and seen great performance when refactoring to use said pointers properly; however, I'm wondering if there is some way that we could automate the detection of when a pointer is actually misused and could qualify for a unique_ptr instead.

This would be both for "sweeping" the code base (clang-tidy style) to make the refactoring burden easier, as well as for an ongoing mode, of detecting when pointer misuse happens and preventing it at the "precommit" level.

I've flipped thru various articles and stack overflow posts, as well as flipped thru both gcc and clang compiler options, and haven't quite found what I've been looking for.

Comment: Correctly deciding this will need to consider all the code together, not just one translation unit at a time, and I'm not sure if there's a good way to set up clang-tidy for that. You could maybe get a custom clang-tidy checker to provide some output on each TU, and then have something combine those results.

Comment: Thanks for the chatter, my question wasn't so much "how can we do this with tidy", but rather, is there some "sweeper" (whether that be a compiler flag, or just about any other tool) to help make life a little easier. The other comments in this thread are super valid along both inspecting code, and make sure the code is modeled correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of an automated way to do this, but you could:

1. Temporarily replace *all* `shared_ptr` with `unique_ptr`
2. Every time the compiler complains (due to attempted copies):

   - Work out whether a move will do
   - If yes, the `unique_ptr` is sufficient
   - Otherwise, go back to `shared_ptr`
3. Every other time, a `unique_ptr` is sufficient

This is quite a blunt approach, though; ultimately there's no substitute for really analysing each usage with your brain. And, yeah, I know that's a bit of a pain with a large codebase. More than anything else the solution to that (if you could go back in time, anyway) is not to introduce mounting technical debt over ten years!

Comment: In addition to this, have more junior developers do the work as part of their education on pointer semantics.  They will hate this job so much, that they will vow to be more thoughtful on their pointer use in future.

Comment: Heh, I like that. You'll still have to review every one of their suggestions, so it's not really _less_ effort for the OP personally ... but I suppose that's true of any big task that you hive off to your underlings, while doing so has its benefits for the peeps doing the monkey work as well as the organisation (and our industry) in the long run. _(tl;dr: ya gotta teach)_

Comment: Also works for detecting when `public` functions should really be made `private`.

Comment: @dan04: Ish. I wouldn't make a function `private` _just_ because it _can_ be; a function's access level should make sense for that function, even if you're not currently relying on it being liberal. But one _might_ argue that it's likely your approach will work in general unless you've implemented loads of things you don't need yet (which some people advise against!)

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is basically what we've been doing (drill down on modeling/design, and drill down on move to unique_ptr and see what screams), then wash/rinse repeat. 100% agree that there is no free lunch, besides making sure tech debt doesn't add up. We're addressing that in many ways, part of the byproducts of being an insanely fast moving startup. This is where the second part of my question came in, asking if there was a way to detect this on commit. Obviously good CRs help :) but sometimes things can get missed, hence the question.

Comment: @JonKohler Have fun :P

Answer (score 0):

I would have another approach. Take like one class that contains one `std::shared_ptr`. Try to see why it's a shared (mostly to be able to copy the class or to hold the pointer at many places). See what solution you can use.

The way I do the refactor is I take a theoretical look at the context. Is, on paper, the lifetime of the two classes (the container of the shared pointer and the pointer) together is known? Is their lifetime tied or unrelated? Work it out by linking the lifetime of those two classes together or to a system. Try to make your model clear. Document it. Naturally, by grouping lifetimes together into logical units you can drag in more classes that are related.

Then, after your model is done, translate that into your code. Do it as incrementally as possible and plan it carefully. **Only** use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` when you must know about the lifetime of the object your manipulating. Otherwise, consider (non-owning) raw pointers or references. The code should be as close to your model as possible. If something's wrong when implementing, revise your model.

Comment: If you don't know about the lifetime of the object you're manipulating, that's a serious problem and must be addressed. Using a raw pointer just masks that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there is a lot of function that doesn't need to know about the ownership and lifetime of its parameters. For example I don't know why I should pass around a `std::unique_ptr` around everywhere when I only need to observe the object.

Comment: If you want to observe an object then you need to know whether it's alive. I didn't say "never use raw pointers", just "don't use raw pointers to mask when you _don't know the lifetime of an object_", because you should always know the lifetime of an object and your choice of pointer doesn't affect that. As an aside, C++20 will introduce `observer_ptr` which is basically just a raw pointer but signifies clearly the intent you just described; I'm not yet sure exactly how I feel about it but there we go.